# Kendo Grid HeaderTemplate .Sum not working as in FooterTemplate

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, kendo-ui

I want to **summarize** the values of the column `TotalPrice` of the Grid.

It works fine with the Footer.Template:

```
.Columns(col => col.Bound(o => o.TotalPrice)
                   .FooterTemplate(@<text>Sum: @item.Sum</text>))
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
     .Server()
     ... )
```

[image]

**But I want:**

But I want to have this row with Sum etc. **above of the data rows, as first row**!!
Does anybody know how this works, either with a built-in functionality, or a stable workaround.

**Try and error:**

with HeaderTemplate:

```
.Columns(col => col.Bound(o => o.TotalPrice)
                   .HeaderTemplate(@<text>Sum: @item.Sum</text>))
```

I get following:

```
Compilation Error
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

Compiler Error Message: CS1593: Delegate 'System.Action' does not take 1 arguments

Source Error:    

Line 54:           columns.Bound(o => o.TotalPrice).HeaderTemplate(@<text>Sum: @item.Sum</text>);
```

Answer (score 0):

Old question, so it's possible the Kendo Grid has changed.

You can run *server-side* code in the `.HeaderTemplate` with an `Action` (or `Func`), for example:

```
columns.Bound(o => o.TotalPrice)
       .HeaderTemplate((x) => { 
           return Model.PreCalculatedTotalPrice.ToString("0.00");
       });
```

This assumes `PreCalculatedTotalPrice` is a decimal property on your view's model (not the grid's bound model).

The `x` always appears to be null, so not entirely sure what this is for / passed.

As it's server-side, you can run any normal .Net code (`if`s etc)